# Why is this throwing MalformedURLException?

Tags: java, url, uri

I am trying to feed the constructor of the FXMLLoader the path of my .fmxl file. I've looked all over the web and have tried any work around I could and it doesn't work.

*I'm using Java 9 SDK*

Code:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URI;
    import javafx.fxml.*;

    public class TestFX {

public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
    File file = new File("W:\\fxml\\Hello_World.fxml");
    URI urii = URI.create(file.toString());
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(urii.toURL());
   }
}
```

Comment: Because it is not a url. Where is the file `.fxml` located relative to your project? Try; `FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(); loader.setLocation(main.class.getResource("Hello_World.fxml"));`

Comment: main is not from Application so you may have to just add the path; `loader.setLocation("Hello_World.fxml"‌​);` I have not tried this though hopefully someone who knows a lot about this will be here soon to help. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html

Comment: The first arg in the constructor must be of type URL... Not String. And if you use the .setLocation method that must also contain a URL. Not a String. Therefore, I can't use a path that's a String. I want to use a local file from my machine and feed the loader that.